# Navigation Submenu is not coming up

Tags: html, css

I have created a Navigation menu with sub menu. Can anyone please help me to  find out why sub menu is coming as part of main menu?

Navigation have options like: Home, About, My Portfolio...
My Portfolio have menu options: Web Development, Motion...

**Issue:** Web Development should have sub menu: Bootstrap, CSS but rather it is coming as part of main menu.`<div id="Navigation"><ul class="Navigation"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>/div>`

```css
body {
  background: #c4c7cb;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(cover, #FFF, #D1D1D1);
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(cover, #e8eaec, #a4a8ae);
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(cover, #e8eaec, #a4a8ae);
  background-image: radial-gradient(cover, #e8eaec, #a4a8ae)
}
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.Navigation {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.Navigation li {
  height: auto;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  font: 12px"Bonveno", "Century Gothic";
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) inset, 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.Navigation a {
  padding: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  display: block;
}
.Navigation li ul {
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -11px;
  padding: 0;
}
.Navigation li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
.Navigation li:hover,
a:hover {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
```

```html
<div id="Navigation">
  <ul class="Navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">My Portfolio</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Web Development</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Motion Graphics</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Flash Animation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Logo Design</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Photography</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have a CSS rule for `.Navigation li:hover ul { display: block; }` that I believe you want to show the second level menu on first level item hover. But this rule is also applying to the third level menu (that means all `ul` under the first level item hovers are applied `display: block;`), you may want to use

`.Navigation li:hover > ul` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```css
body {
  background: #c4c7cb;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(cover, #FFF, #D1D1D1);
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(cover, #e8eaec, #a4a8ae);
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(cover, #e8eaec, #a4a8ae);
  background-image: radial-gradient(cover, #e8eaec, #a4a8ae)
}
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.Navigation {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.Navigation li {
  height: auto;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  font: 12px"Bonveno", "Century Gothic";
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) inset, 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.Navigation a {
  padding: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  display: block;
}
.Navigation li ul {
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -11px;
  padding: 0;
}
.Navigation li ul li ul {
  display: none !important;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -11px;
  padding: 0;
}
.Navigation li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
.Navigation li ul li:hover ul {
  display: block !important;
}
.Navigation li:hover,
a:hover {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
```

```html
<div id="Navigation">
  <ul class="Navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">My Portfolio</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Web Development</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Motion Graphics</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Flash Animation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Logo Design</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Photography</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please also help me with aligning sub menu to right side, I tried couple of things but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to adjust your on-hover state rules so that they apply to elements you need to when you need it to.

```
.Navigation li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.Navigation li > ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

**See snippet below** (note: I've reduced menu item widths slightly to fit them into the preview pane)

```css
.Navigation li > ul li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 127px;
}

.Navigation li > ul li > ul li {
    float: none;
}

.Navigation li > ul li {
    position: relative;
}

body{
  background: #c4c7cb;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(cover, #FFF,#D1D1D1 );
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(cover, #e8eaec, #a4a8ae);
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(cover, #e8eaec, #a4a8ae);
  background-image: radial-gradient(cover, #e8eaec, #a4a8ae)
}

html{
  min-height:100%;
}

.Navigation{
 height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.Navigation > li:first-child {
    margin: 0px;
}

.Navigation li  {
 height: auto;
 width: 115px;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 list-style: none;
 font:12px "Bonveno", "Century Gothic";
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #eee;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255, .9) inset, 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
 border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left:10px;
}

.Navigation a{       
 padding:13px;
 text-decoration: none; 
 color:#333;
 text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
 display: block;
}
.Navigation li ul{
 display: none;
 height: auto;         
 margin-left: -11px;
 padding: 0;  
} 

.Navigation li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.Navigation li > ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.Navigation li:hover, a:hover {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
```

```html
<div id="Navigation">
   <ul class="Navigation">
             <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">My Portfolio</a>
           <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Web Development</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Motion Graphics</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Flash Animation</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Logo Design</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
           </ul>         
           </li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>            
            </ul>
        </div>
```

From here, you can simply add further styles (if necessary) to sub-menu items 2 levels, or deeper, to appear to the right of the parent menu item (rather than below).

**Align sub-menu to right:**

The rules below serve only to demonstrate how to get you there. I'd recommend refining them.

```
.Navigation li > ul li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 127px;
}

.Navigation li > ul li > ul li {
    float: none;
}

.Navigation li > ul li {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please also help me with aligning sub menu to right side, I tried couple of things but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background: #c4c7cb;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(cover, #FFF, #D1D1D1);
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(cover, #e8eaec, #a4a8ae);
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(cover, #e8eaec, #a4a8ae);
  background-image: radial-gradient(cover, #e8eaec, #a4a8ae)
}
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.Navigation {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.Navigation li {
  height: auto;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  font: 12px"Bonveno", "Century Gothic";
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) inset, 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.Navigation a {
  padding: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  display: block;
}
.Navigation li ul {
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -11px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.Navigation li ul li ul {
  display: none !important;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -11px;
  padding: 0;
}
.Navigation li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
.Navigation li ul li:hover ul {
  display: block !important;
}
.Navigation li:hover,
a:hover {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
```

```html
<div id="Navigation">
  <ul class="Navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">My Portfolio</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Web Development</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Motion Graphics</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Flash Animation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Logo Design</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Photography</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please also help me with aligning sub menu to right side, I tried couple of things but nothing worked